# In UWP how to display a messagebox from a synchronous function (ie. not async)

Tags: c#, uwp

Is there a way to wrap the UWP async function for creating dialog boxes in such a way that they can be called from a normal method without the async keyword?  Example:

```
var msgbox = new ContentDialog
             {
                   Title   = "Error",
                   Content = "Already at the top of the stack",
                   CloseButtonText = "OK"
             };
             await msgbox.ShowAsync();
```

Comment: For clarification: Do you also need the result from the dialog before you continue execution (like normal `MessageBox`)? I assume so but please verify.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do this at the moment. If you try to block waiting for the dialog to close, your app will deadlock.

Comment: Maybe its possible to use Task.Wait method on a ShowAsync() from a non-UI thread?  Meaning you start the dialog from the UI thread, save the Task variable, and pass it over to a worker thread to Wait with out causing UI-dead lock because its a worker thread?  or maybe you could use a UI synchronization context on a worker thread to ShowAsync the contentdialog? (is that possible?)

Comment: another possiblity... Dispatch to UI thread from worker thread to ShowAsync Dialog, then get the Task back from ShowAsync and from worker thread call Wait()?  possible?

Comment: There is no supported way to do this. It's a known gap from WPF / WinForms / Win32.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it (I saw this in some live demo back when UWP was just introduced):

```
var msgbox = new ContentDialog
             {
                   Title   = "Error",
                   Content = "Already at the top of the stack",
                   CloseButtonText = "OK"
             };
             var ignored = msgbox.ShowAsync();
```

This works as expected in a non-async void method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Task<ContentDialogResult> MsgBox(string title, string content)
{
    Task<ContentDialogResult> X = null;

    var msgbox = new ContentDialog
    {
        Title = title,
        Content = content,
        CloseButtonText = "OK"
    };

    try
    {
        X = msgbox.ShowAsync().AsTask<ContentDialogResult>();
        return X;
    }
    catch { 
        return null;
    }
}

private void B1BtnBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MsgBox("Beep", "Already at the top of stack");
    return; 

    // ^^^ Careful here. MsgBox returns with an active task
    // running to display dialog box.  This works because
    // the next statement is a return that directly 
    // returns to the UI message loop.  And the 
    // ContentDialog is modal meaning it disables 
    // the page until ok is clicked in the dialog box.
}
```